# How do I match individual CSS attributes using RegEx

Tags: css, regex

I'm trying to expand a minified CSS file (don't ask) to make it human readable.
I've managed to get most of the expanding done but I'm stuck at a very weird case that I can't figure out.

I have CSS that looks like this:

```
.innerRight {
border:0;color:#000;width:auto;padding-top:0;margin:0;
}
a {
color:#000;text-decoration:underline;font-size:12px;
}
p,small,ul,li {
color:#000;font-size:12px;padding:0;
}
```

I've tried `(.+):(.+);` as the search and `\t\1: \2;\n` as the replace. The find RegEx is valid, the only problem is that it matches the entire line of attributes. I've tried the non-greedy character, but I must not be putting it in the right place.

What the above find RegEx matches is:

```
0: border:0;color:#000;width:auto;padding-top:0;margin:0;
1: color:#000;text-decoration:underline;font-size:12px;
2: color:#000;font-size:12px;padding:0;
```

While those are technically correct matches, I need it to match `border:0;`, `color:#000;`, etc separately for my replace to work.

Comment: What programming language are you doing this with?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier just to insert a line break directly after each semicolon and ignoring the context. Or do you need a general solution which will work with a semicolon for eaxmple inside a string (which is quite unlikely in CSS)?

Comment: Replace ';' with ';\n\r' ... wich programming-language?

Comment: Or you could just use one of the many CSS formatters/beautifiers online or built into an editor: http://www.google.de/search?q=css+(beautifier+OR+formatter)

Comment: Programming language independent. I could use a formatter/beautifier, but I'm taking this opportunity to get some RegEx practice in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this - use non-greedy matching. This works for me

```
(.+?):(.+?);
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget the colon. Just replace all semicolons with ";\n".

In Javascript, for example, you could write:

```
text = text.replace(/;/gm,";\n");
```

I would further refine that to address leading-space issues, etc., but this will put every style rule on its own line.

Comment: Do this only if there is no comment, URL, or string that contains that character. You might also want to check if there is not already a new line following the `;`.

Comment: @Gumbo: True. I should post a macro I have that does all this formatting, and I will once I get in to the office.